# How to get data from runAction

Tags: php, yii

I have this code in my view page:

```
<?php if(isset($journal)&&($keyword=="%")){
                            return Yii::$app->controller->runAction('journalslist',  ['publisherID'=>$journal['publisher_id'], 'partial'=>1]);
                    }
```

How can I get `'publisherID'` and `'partial'` in  `actionJournalList()` in the controller?!!!  `var_dump($_POST)` shows empty array and `Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParams()` just have `$_GET` data? How can I config `runAction` to POST data?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there shouldn't really be a reason to ever call runAction explicitly as it does not match up with the MVC design.

Explain what you're trying to achieve overall and you'll find a better answer. For now i'd say, look at the current controller/action that is rendering that view and have it check `if(isset($journal)&&($keyword=="%")){` and route the information from the existing action to your view instead of trying to call a new action.

Alternatively run a redirect.

Comment: You are right Harlan, I changed my code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

POST method is only for `form`. If you redirect to an action, This means GET. There is no way for redirecting with POST. `$_POST` will be filled only when you submit a form.